"message": "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCustomers = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await auth.getcustomer({ name: '', orgId: '', entryId: '', id: ''});
      console.log('response in use effect: ', res.data.data.customers);
      setData(transformData(res.data.data.customers));
      return res; 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching customers:', error);
      return null; 
    }
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await fetchCustomers();

    if (result) {
    } else {
    }
  };

  fetchData(); 
}, [auth]);

so basically what im trying to do is to fecth the custumers using useEffct the code working fine locally but when i try to build it it gives me this error
"message": "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void

im using the API as follows
  const handleGetCustomer = (
    params: GetCustomerParams,
    errorCallback?: ErrCallbackType
  ) => {
    return axios
      .post(authConfig.getcustomerEndPoint, params, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${globalToken}`,
        },
      })
  };

and here are the Params:
export type GetCustomerParams = {
  name: string
  entryId: string
  orgId: string 
  id:string
}

any guidelines would be highly appreciated

its a type error, the compiler doesn't know except "data" object in res. The best way would be to define an interface for it based on api response or set the type of res to any., such as:
 `const res:any = await auth.getcustomer({ name: '', orgId: '', entryId: '', id: ''});`


exactly thats the solution
Thank u
